# How to create single table from sql script in mysql workbench

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I know how to import  all table from existing database to diagram (reverse engineer):

1. Using live connection.
2. Using sql dump script (whole sql dump).

What I don't know is to create single table using sql script.

example:
I create diagram manually using workbench. Let's say I created this 2 tables:

1. user
2. gender

And then when I want to add 1 more table which called **user_post**. instead create this manually by clicking in workbench GUI, I like to create table book from existing sql script (only part of whole my sql dump). Because its really hard if I create it using GUI add column since table book have so many column.

**UPDATE**:

if above explanation still not clearly. Just imagine if i want to copy Wordpress table wp_post structure into my new diagram. like following:

[image]

img url: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qj3bb.png

its really takes time, if i create the table using GUI. And more easier to just dump the wp_post table stucture into workbench.

Is it possible to do this in workbench?

Comment: Would `CREATE TABLE` be a possibility here, or am I missing something?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen yes, i want to create table from SQL Script ex: `CREATE TABLE book (id INT PRIMARY KEY ...)` instead create table by clicking the GUI. Note: Sorry for my english